# I want to use Index and Match combined with LEFT and RIGHT in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables, 1 with ZIP codes and Zones and 1 with Weights, Zones and Values.
I got the `INDEX` + `MATCH` working to get the Zone Code, but can't link the weight with zone to get the correct amount.

[image]

So I will add the weight as ex. 450 and need to search inside the range 0-500 etc.
I have tried using the following `LEFT` and `RIGHT` measures to get the correct row but can't combine them with the `MATCH` and `INDEX` row:

```
=(LEFT(J2,SEARCH("-",J2)-1)+0<=$X$3)

=(RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-SEARCH("-",J2))+0>=$X$3)
```

But I can't get it working with different Google and Youtube tutorials unfortunately.

I also tried the following formula:

```
=INDEX($K$2:$R$12,MATCH(X3,J2:J12,0),MATCH(X4,$K$1:$R$1,0))
```

This one works when I enter the full weight range (0-500 ex), but can't get it working together with the `RIGHT`/`LEFT` function.

My weight will be in cell `X3` and the Zone will be displayed in `X4`.

Comment: I would not put a range in column J but the upper limit of each range.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=XLOOKUP(K8,VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(J2:J5,"-")),XLOOKUP(K7,K1:M1,K2:M5,,0),,-1)
```

Result:

[image]

It would be more simple if you would put only lower or upper limit as @Solar Mike suggested:

```
=XLOOKUP(K8,J2:J5,XLOOKUP(K7,K1:M1,K2:M5,,0),,1)
```

Result:

[image]